# Getting started with UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

My app is trying to mimic the functionality of a UITableView by simply adding little sub views underneath each other. This just isn't working anymore for a few reasons (when a user deletes a 'row' there is blank space between the one above it and the one below it, users need an 'infinite' amount of rows and I only built 20).

So, does anyone know of any great UITableView tutorials? Specifically I need to:
- Customize the appearance
- Add rows at the tap of a button
- Attach 2 buttons to each row
- Attach a UITextField to each row (or just have the label be editable)
- Save the text/text field for each row (like with NSUserDefaults).
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your using Storyboards, check this tutorial out http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend you watch all WWDC videos on table views. They range from introductory to some interesting advanced techniques. Additionally, there are Stanford videos available for free in iTunes.